# get facebook friend email ID

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I want to know how to get Facebook friend's email ID. I am showing Facebook friend using `FBFriendPickerController`. But it is not giving me friend's email ID. I am running query for this but that is also returning nil value.

Please help me how to get friend's email ID in iOS

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access email id's of facebook friends. 
From [facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) site

> There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.